# Why does disabling lazy loading cause related tables to have no results?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

Given:

```
        public SomeEntity Read(int primaryKey)
        {
            SomeEntity myEntity;
            using (var context = new MyEntities2())
            {
                context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;//This line is wacky
                myEntity = context.SomeEntities.SingleOrDefault(ct => ct.PrimaryKey == primaryKey);                     
                if (myEntity == null)
                    return myEntity;

                //Force eager Load...
                var bypassDeferredExecution = myEntity.RelatedTable1.ToList();
                var bypassDeferredExecution2 = myEntity.RelatedTable2.ToList();
            }
            return myEntity;
        }
```

If I set `LazyLoadingEnabled = false` then **myEntity.RelatedTable1.Count == 0**.
Leave at the default `LazyLoadingEnabled = true` then myEntity.RelatedTable1.Count == 2.

My understanding is that Lazy Loading and Eager Loading are polar opposites.  I forced eager loading.  I expect my related table (a cross reference table) to have 2 results whether or not I use lazy loading. So in my mind these results make no sense.

Why does lazy loading impact my results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `Include` to eagerly load related entities:

```
myEntity = context.SomeEntities
                  .Include("RelatedTable1")
                  .Include("RelatedTable2")
                  .SingleOrDefault(ct => ct.PrimaryKey == primaryKey);
```

Setting *Lazy Loading* to false won't cause it happen automatically.

Comment: If it is just a matter of when the query is executed then why does calling ToList() fail to correct the issue?  `myEntity.RelatedTable1.ToList()` I expect LINQ to SQL will update my result from 0 results to 2 results.  The reason why this does not happen is still unclear.

Comment: Because when you set *lazy loading* to `false` EF will not send any query agains DB unless you explicitly request one, using `Context` instance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using lazy loading, then there needs to be a LINQ to Entities `Include` method call to identify the (foreign keyed) tables to eagerly load.

Answer (score 0):

Navigation property isn't query, it's enumerable collection. You have 2 ways to get it from DB:
- Lazy loading (will be loaded on the first access to property)
- Eager loading (will be loaded after executing main query if you add `Include({propertyName}` method

So, if you turned off lazy loading and don't add `Include` methods to the query each navigation property will be empty (empty collection or null value for single entities)

The following code should work for your case:

```
myEntity = context.SomeEntities
.Include("RelatedTable1")
.Include("RelatedTable2")
.SingleOrDefault(ct => ct.PrimaryKey == primaryKey);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lazy loading defers the initialization of an object until it is needed. In this case it will automatically execute a query to the DB to load the object requested.

Eager loading loads a specific set of related objects along with the objects that were explicitly requested in the query.

So in order to use Eager Loading you need to specify the related objects that you want to load.

In EF you can achieve this using the method `Include` from `ObjectQuery`.

```
context.Entity.Include("RelatedObject");
```